# Get and execute command in HTA

Tags: hta

I'm new in scripting. I need the code to receive some arguments and execute it in hidden cmd in HTA.

the command to execute is 
netsh wlan set hosted mode=allow ssid="name" key="pwd"

Here i want to get "name" and "pwd" from submit box and execute the above command in hidden hta.

I made it, but not working properly. See

```
 <script language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript">
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strOut=""

sub StartProgram
cmdarg="%comspec% /c netsh wlan set hosted mode=allow ssid=" & T1.value "key=" & T2.value
 iReturn=objShell.Run(cmdarg, 0, True)
If iReturn = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Success"
Else
     MsgBox "Cannot Start" 
End If
TraceOut.innerHTML= strOut
end sub
</script>
```

Comment: "not working properly" is not a description of a problem. Please [edit] your post and be more specific - we can't see your screen from where we are, so we have no idea what "not working properly" means. We can't help if you can't clearly describe the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the whole problem, but at the very least:

```
cmdarg="%comspec% /c netsh wlan set hosted mode=allow ssid=" & T1.value "key=" & T2.value
```

should be

```
cmdarg="%comspec% /c netsh wlan set hosted mode=allow ssid=" & T1.value & " key=" & T2.value
```

In other words, you left an ampersand out after `T1.value`, and left a space out before `key=`.

Comment: Thank you, I found by self in the same day I posted the question. Todd, that was I wanted :)